# AngularJs $invalid isn't working in this situation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Hello, 
I have a problem with the form validation.
I have the following code :

```
<div>
<form name="formRankMax">
    <div class="input-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': formRankMax.inputMax.$invalid && formRankMax.inputMax.$invalid }">
        <span class="input-group-addon">Max</span>
        <input class="form-control has-feedback" name="inputMax" type="number" placeholder="Maximum" ng-model="selectedItem.range.max" min="{{selectedItem.range.min}}" >
    </div>
</form>
```

```
<div>
<form name="formRankMin">
    <div class="input-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': formRankMin.inputMin.$dirty && formRankMin.inputMin.$invalid }">
        <span class="input-group-addon">Min</span>
        <input class="form-control has-feedback" name="inputMin" type="number" placeholder="Maximum" ng-model="selectedItem.range.min" min="0" max="{{selectedItem.range.max}}" >
    </div>
</form>
```

As you can see the min value of "inputMax" is the same than in the ng-model of "inputMin". 
But when I enter for exemple 10 in "inputMin" and 9 in "inputMax" the validation doesn't works. (but there is a tooltip which tell me to put another value)

Do you have an idea to make it work ?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve exactly, but the following part of your code looks like you accidently forgot to change a property when copy pasting;

```
<div class="input-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': formRankMax.inputMax.$invalid && formRankMax.inputMax.$invalid }">
```

this should probably be

```
<div class="input-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': formRankMax.inputMax.$dirty && formRankMax.inputMax.$invalid }">
```

Also, when using AngularJS form validation it is advisable to set the novalidate attribute on your form element as such;

```
<form name="formRankMax" novalidate>
```

Comment: Thank you for the $dirty ( I forgot to change it) but it still doesn't work. What I'm trying to achieve is to have two inputs number. The min of the first input is the max of the second and the max of the second is the min of the first.

Comment: I found the solution with another post. I was using a previous version of angularjs. The problem is now fixed. Thank you for your answer and your time.